# WebServiceMessageCallback, message cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

I'm using Spring WS to invoke an XML web service.  When I try to inspect "message" in doWithMessage method of WebServiceMessageCallback, I get "message cannot be resolved to a variable."  The code does compile though but doesn't seem to be logging the messages.

```
this.webserviceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source,
new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
    @Override
    public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message)
            throws IOException, TransformerException {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            // log the SOAP request
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            message.writeTo(out);
            LOG.debug("SOAP Request Payload: " + new String(out.toByteArray()));
            }
        }
        }, result);
```